# Undefined behaviour when taking string input through scanf

Tags: c++, arrays, scanf

I have declared a character array of size 4. When I take a string  input even of size 5, the program prints the correct string. Why does this happen? With 8 characters too, it prints the right string but with 9 characters it gives an error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char s[4];
    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("%s",s);
}
```

Error when I try to take input as a 9 character long string:

```
abcdefghi
*** stack smashing detected ***: /home/shivam/Study/standardproblems/stacks/temp terminated
abcdefghiAborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Undefined behavior means that *anything* can happen.

Comment: @BoPersson No, it means anything can happen as far as the ISO C standard is concerned.

Comment: @Kaz - If you write to a random memory location, that might reprogram your display card, format your hard drive, or - if you work [at the Pentagon](http://time.com/4348494/pentagon-nuclear-floppy-disks/) - initiate a nuclear launch sequence.

Comment: @BoPersson Rather, none of those actions would not be classified as ISO C as nonconforming. Undefined behavior is a very broad category, which encompasses useful implementation extensions. When you use `__builtin_expect` in GCC, that is also undefined behavior; yet it will not initiate a nuclear launch sequence.